# Google double click advertisement SDK Strange behavior in iOS

Tags: ios, ads, google-dfp, double-click-advertising

I'm using google double click interstitial advertise in my app (DFPInterstitial) and there is some strange behavior. When user clicking on advertise it opens it's content in the same popup window. In AdMob it opens in safari. So the question is how can I make DFPInterstitial interaction open it's content in safari as AdMob interstitial do ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've find solution. [Here](https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/1656921?hl=en) in the last section "Target window: new browser window".